# Mega-menu on hover invisible

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I cannot solve. There is a menu, you need to hover over one of the items to drop a mega-menu. This happens, but as soon as I try to move the cursor over this menu-menu, it disappears immediately.

The mega menu has a `position: absolute`, but this is always done, and everything works for everyone. I can't understand what the problem is

```css
.menu__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 22px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  background-color: rgba(37, 44, 55);
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  top: 80px;
}

.menu__list li:hover>.menu__dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  background: rgba(37, 44, 55, 0);
}

.header ._container {
  max-width: 1470px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 45px;
}

.header._active {
  background: #252c37;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.header__row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo img {
  width: 96px;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

.header__logo p {
  width: 156px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-opened {
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.menu-opened._active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 100%;
  background: #64686F;
}

.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  height: 365px;
}

.menu-opened__row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 365px;
}

.menu-opened__left {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-opened__right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 407px;
  flex: 0 0 407px;
  background: url("../img/menu/bg.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.menu__list li:hover>.menu__dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu__list li {
  margin: 0px 36px 0px 0px;
}

.menu__list li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu__link {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 22px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  background-color: rgba(37, 44, 55);
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="_container">
    <div class="header__row">
      <a href="/" class="header__logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        <p>Программное обеспечение для сферы бытовых услуг</p>
      </a>
      <div class="header__menu menu">
        <div class="menu__icon icon-menu">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu__body">
          <ul class="menu__list">
            <li><a href="nashi-avto.html" class="menu__link">Товары и цены</a></li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="#" class="menu__link _dropdown">Услуги</a>
              <span class="menu__arrow"></span>
              <div class="menu__dropdown">
                <ul class="menu__sub-list">
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-link">Программный комплекс</a></li>
                  <ul class="menu__sub-sub-list">
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Химчистка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Приёмка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Приёмка</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Рабочее Место</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Цех</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Рассылки</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Клиент</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Call-центр</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Подпись</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link"> Фото</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-sub-link">Сканер</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-link">Мобильное приложение интегрированное</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-link">Сайт интегрированный</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-link">Дополнительные опции</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="menu__sub-link">Автомат</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Поддержка</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">О нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Информация</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="header__cart"></a>
      <div class="header__contacts">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```